# How to find the built-in bluetooth adapter in Toshiba satellite c55-896 laptop

Tags: kernel, bluetooth, atheros, adapter, firmware

I have been using Ubuntu for over a year, but recently I have encountered an old problem again.

When I First installed Ubuntu, it said 'No adapter found' in the Bluetooth section. I want to buy a wireless mouse, and couldn't figure out a way around this. I can either use my ports for an external bluetooth, or buy a new laptop.

Can someone help me figure out why my bluetooth isn't being recognized?

the result of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb`  is :

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: XAVi Technologies Corp. Device [1b9a:28a2]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:f920]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b446 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0930:0227 Toshiba Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

[Bug report in launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-utopic/+bug/1475639)

Result of `uname -r` is `3.16.0-44-generic`

Result of rfkill list is:

```
 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Result of `dmesg | grep -i blue` is:

```
[   16.841906] toshiba_bluetooth: Detected Toshiba ACPI Bluetooth device - installing RFKill handler
[   16.841925] toshiba_bluetooth: Re-enabling Toshiba Bluetooth
[   16.972752] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
[   16.972802] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   16.972810] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   16.972813] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   16.972821] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   17.103743] Bluetooth: Patch file not found ar3k/AthrBT_0x31010100.dfu
[   17.103747] Bluetooth: Loading patch file failed
[   19.390808] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   19.390819] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   19.390824] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   19.412213] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   19.412216] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   19.412223] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[ 2101.801424] toshiba_bluetooth: Re-enabling Toshiba Bluetooth
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the terminal result of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb`

Comment: Um... I have a question: Are you absolutely heart-set on a Bluetooth wireless mouse?  If you have a spare USB port, a Logitech wireless mouse (with one of their Unifying Receivers, so it's not Bluetooth) would give you the ability to have a wireless mouse.  It'd also probably be a little cheaper than a Bluetooth mouse, but still be wireless.  (It also prevents you from having to buy a new laptop)

Comment: Its not just mouse... I have had the beats pill speaker for a while now, but only use it with my phone, and I would like to give it a try. And also I don't know if its related but the wireless light(Fn+F12) on my laptop doesn't work

Comment: What is Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Comment: Hold on. It is supported. I will change the answer. Please add output of `uname -r`.

Comment: And also `rfkill list` and `dmesg | grep -i blue`

Comment: I have added the results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `linux-firmware` package does not contain firmware required by this module. It is shown by `Patch file not found ar3k/AthrBT_0x31010100.dfu`.

This can be fixed by installing `linux-firmware` package that has the firmware. Run in terminal

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/linux-firmware_1.144%2Bar3012_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb
```

Your bluetooth should work after reboot.

**Update** I sent this firmware to `linux-firmware` maintainers and it has been added. Sooner or later it will get into Ubuntu repos.

Comment: Thanks... I've just rebooted my pc and it worked. Thanks for all your help.