# Patch file not found ar3k/AthrBT_0x31010000.dfu

Tags: bluetooth, acer, 22.04

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my Acer Aspire ES1-512 and I'm getting this message every time before it boots. My Bluetooth is not working due to this error.

I have tried [How to find the built-in bluetooth adapter in Toshiba satellite c55-896 laptop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/649483/how-to-find-the-built-in-bluetooth-adapter-in-toshiba-satellite-c55-896-laptop), but it's giving this error:

```
dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'linux-firmware*.deb': No such file or directory
```

Comment: This was reported in [bug 1969853](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1969853) and a fix is in the proposed repository as of 2022-05-04. The fix will likely be rolled out to everyone soon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try my solution:

1. Download `linux-firmware_1.201.tar.xz` from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.201.tar.xz (you can visit https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/linux-firmware for more details).
2. Extract `linux-firmware_1.201.tar.xz` and copy the `ar3k` folder into `/lib/firmware`.
3. Restart your computer.

Comment: thanks buddy, I tried similar step, the problem is resolved now

Comment: @AbhishekSonkar Can you write up your eventual solution and then mark it as an Accepted Answer?

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution - it worked perfectly. However, I have to ask: why? Why after running Ubuntu for about 5 years straight, this is now required?