# Ubuntu 22.04 bluetooth adapter is not availible

Tags: bluetooth

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop Asus N551JM. After installation, Bluetooth adapter is not available. How I can solve this problem?

```
sudo dmesg |grep -i bluetooth

[    3.772671] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.772699] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    3.772701] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.772705] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.772707] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.772711] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.935429] Bluetooth: Patch file not found ar3k/AthrBT_0x11020000.dfu
[    3.935472] Bluetooth: Loading patch file failed
[    7.652405] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    7.652409] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    7.652412] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized

    inxi -Fxxxz

    System:
      Kernel: 5.15.0-25-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.2.0
        Desktop: GNOME 42.0 tk: GTK 3.24.33 wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM3 42.0
        Distro: Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish)
    Machine:
      Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: N551JM v: 1.0
        serial: <superuser required>
      Mobo: ASUSTeK model: N551JM v: 1.0 serial: <superuser required>
        UEFI: American Megatrends v: N551JM.204 date: 10/06/2014
    Battery:
      ID-1: BAT0 charge: 53.4 Wh (100.0%) condition: 53.4/56.2 Wh (95.1%)
        volts: 10.8 min: 10.8 model: ASUSTeK N551-52 type: Li-ion serial: N/A
        status: Not charging
      Device-1: hidpp_battery_0 model: Logitech Wireless Keyboard K270
        serial: <filter> charge: 100% (should be ignored) rechargeable: yes
        status: Discharging
    CPU:
      Info: dual core model: Intel Core i5-4200H bits: 64 type: MT MCP
        smt: enabled arch: Haswell rev: 3 cache: L1: 128 KiB L2: 512 KiB L3: 3 MiB
      Speed (MHz): avg: 1297 high: 1298 min/max: 800/3400 cores: 1: 1298
        2: 1297 3: 1297 4: 1296 bogomips: 22348
      Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
    Graphics:
      Device-1: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics vendor: ASUSTeK
        driver: i915 v: kernel ports: active: eDP-1 empty: DP-1,HDMI-A-1,HDMI-A-2
        bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:0416 class-ID: 0300
      Device-2: NVIDIA GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] vendor: ASUSTeK driver: nvidia
        v: 510.60.02 pcie: speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 16 bus-ID: 01:00.0
        chip-ID: 10de:1392 class-ID: 0302
      Device-3: IMC Networks USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam type: USB driver: uvcvideo
        bus-ID: 3-7:5 chip-ID: 13d3:5188 class-ID: 0e02 serial: <filter>
      Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 compositor: gnome-shell driver: X:
        loaded: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa gpu: i915
        display-ID: :1 screens: 1
      Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1920x1080 s-dpi: 98 s-size: 499x280mm (19.6x11.0")
        s-diag: 572mm (22.5")
      Monitor-1: eDP-1 model: Samsung res: 1920x1080 hz: 60 dpi: 142
        size: 344x194mm (13.5x7.6") diag: 395mm (15.5") modes: 1920x1080
      OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 4600 (HSW GT2)
        v: 4.6 Mesa 22.0.1 compat-v: 3.1 direct render: Yes
    Audio:
      Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio
        driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:03.0 chip-ID: 8086:0c0c
        class-ID: 0403
      Device-2: Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio
        vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
        chip-ID: 8086:8c20 class-ID: 0403
      Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-25-generic running: yes
      Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
      Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
    Network:
      Device-1: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter
        vendor: AzureWave driver: ath9k v: kernel pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1
        bus-ID: 04:00.0 chip-ID: 168c:0034 class-ID: 0280
      IF: wlp4s0 state: up mac: <filter>
      Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
        vendor: ASUSTeK driver: r8169 v: kernel pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1
        port: d000 bus-ID: 05:00.1 chip-ID: 10ec:8168 class-ID: 0200
      IF: enp5s0f1 state: down mac: <filter>
    Bluetooth:
      Device-1: IMC Networks Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth type: USB driver: N/A
        bus-ID: 3-5:4 chip-ID: 13d3:3474 class-ID: e001
    Drives:
      Local Storage: total: 465.76 GiB used: 138.94 GiB (29.8%)
      ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Crucial model: CT500MX500SSD1 size: 465.76 GiB
        speed: 6.0 Gb/s type: SSD serial: <filter> rev: 023 scheme: GPT
    Partition:
      ID-1: / size: 56.02 GiB used: 7.8 GiB (13.9%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda8
      ID-2: /boot/efi size: 95 MiB used: 30.2 MiB (31.8%) fs: vfat
        dev: /dev/sda2
      ID-3: /home size: 42.68 GiB used: 591.3 MiB (1.4%) fs: ext4
        dev: /dev/sda9
    Swap:
      ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 11.44 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%)
        priority: -2 dev: /dev/sda7
    Sensors:
      System Temperatures: cpu: 49.0 C mobo: N/A
      Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 1800
    Info:
      Processes: 248 Uptime: 27m wakeups: 3 Memory: 11.58 GiB
      used: 2.88 GiB (24.8%) Init: systemd v: 249 runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: N/A
      Packages: 1692 apt: 1683 snap: 9 Shell: Bash v: 5.1.16
      running-in: gnome-terminal inxi: 3.3.13
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkmsM.png)

Comment: It is a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1970117  Somebody accidentally removed the ar3k directory from the deb build

Comment: But it is fixable by copying it manually from `linux-firmware`.

Answer (score 1):

Look a this part:

```
[    3.935429] Bluetooth: Patch file not found ar3k/AthrBT_0x11020000.dfu
```

This file is missing.

I had the same problem and solved it with this solution here:

- Download linux-firmware_1.201.tar.xz at http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.201.tar.xz (you can visit https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/linux-firmware for more details)
- Extract linux-firmware_1.201.tar.xz, copy folder ar3k into /lib/firmware
- Restart your computer

The original post where I found the solution is this: [Patch file not found ar3k/AthrBT_0x31010000.dfu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403934/patch-file-not-found-ar3k-athrbt-0x31010000-dfu)

I hope it helps you.