# Bluetooth not working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: bluetooth, lenovo, 22.04, chromebook

I have Ubuntu 22.04 installed on my Lenovo Thinkpad X131e and tried using Wireless Earbuds. But when I opened Bluetooth there were no devices.

Image:
[image: Screenshot Image]

Comment: Please provide details of your hardware. Thank you.

Comment: You need to use the toggle switch.

Comment: i tried using the toggle switch but it dose not work

Comment: @Jordan White, you can try installing [blueman](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/x11/blueman) to see whether it rectifies the problem. If you already have blueman, try the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403934/patch-file-not-found-ar3k-athrbt-0x31010000-dfu)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue` terminal command.

Comment: There is [only Windows Bluetooth drivers for the X131e](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x131e/downloads/ds029441), so we just need some rando to decide to make a Bluetooth adapter for the X131e's kernel.

Comment: [**Related and links therein**](https://askubuntu.com/q/1450767/1130604)