# Bluetooth does not work on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth

##### Specs

I Use Honor magicbook 14 2021.

##### problem

Bluetooth does not turn on through the settings, even after moving the slider nothing turns on.
Bluetooth is enabled in bios,

##### commands that can help

`uname -a`

```
Linux ilya-NMH-WCX9 5.15.0-57-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 24 13:43:17 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`sudo journalctl -u bluetooth.service -b`

```
янв 18 12:58:10 ilya-NMH-WCX9 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
янв 18 12:58:10 ilya-NMH-WCX9 bluetoothd[738]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
янв 18 12:58:10 ilya-NMH-WCX9 bluetoothd[738]: Starting SDP server
янв 18 12:58:10 ilya-NMH-WCX9 bluetoothd[738]: Bluetooth management interface 1>
янв 18 12:58:10 ilya-NMH-WCX9 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
янв 18 13:13:02 ilya-NMH-WCX9 bluetoothd[738]: Terminating
янв 18 13:13:02 ilya-NMH-WCX9 systemd[1]: Stopping Bluetooth service...
янв 18 13:13:02 ilya-NMH-WCX9 bluetoothd[738]: Stopping SDP server
янв 18 13:13:02 ilya-NMH-WCX9 bluetoothd[738]: Exit
янв 18 13:13:02 ilya-NMH-WCX9 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Deactivated succes>
янв 18 13:13:02 ilya-NMH-WCX9 systemd[1]: Stopped Bluetooth service.
янв 18 13:13:02 ilya-NMH-WCX9 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
янв 18 13:13:02 ilya-NMH-WCX9 bluetoothd[7199]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
янв 18 13:13:02 ilya-NMH-WCX9 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
янв 18 13:13:02 ilya-NMH-WCX9 bluetoothd[7199]: Starting SDP server
янв 18 13:13:02 ilya-NMH-WCX9 bluetoothd[7199]: Bluetooth management interface >
```

`$ sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`

```
[    2.287657] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.287689] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    2.287691] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.287695] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.287698] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[     2.287702] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.609085] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.609089] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.609094] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

`rfkill list`

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
```

After use `sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth`

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

But Bluetooth still not working

`sudo lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network`

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCNFA765 [17cb:1103] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e0cc]
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort+ <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin ? routed to IRQ 79
IOMMU group: 7
Region 0: Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ath11k_pci
```

`lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue`

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 27c6:5125 Shenzhen Goodix Technology 
Co.,Ltd. Goodix Fingerprint Device 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0489:e0e1 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0408:1040 Quanta Computer, Inc. 
ov9734_techfront_camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
dmesg: чтение буфера ядра завершилось неудачно: Операция не 
позволена
```

`sudo dmesg | grep -i blue`

```
[    2.287657] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.287689] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    2.287691] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.287695] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.287698] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.287702] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.609085] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.609089] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.609094] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   72.457466] audit: type=1107 audit(1674035959.509:80): pid=741 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=3408 label="snap.slack.slack" peer_pid=738 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 5647.651483] [   7199]     0  7199     2621       98    57344        0             0 bluetoothd
[ 5647.651486] [   7201]     0  7201    39315       92    69632        0             0 bluealsa
[ 5895.671233] audit: type=1107 audit(1674041782.562:610): pid=741 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=24670 label="snap.slack.slack" peer_pid=7199 peer_label="unconfined"
```

Comment: Hi! & Welcome to AskUbuntu! :)  and this is a good question, ill follow it and see if I can help as well

Comment: Can you add the output of `lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network` to your question please?

Comment: @darth_epoxy added

Comment: I am assooming that this is a combined network/bluetooth card because the Honor website is blank under spec's for your model. However it looks like this `Qualcomm Atheros QCNFA765` is not supported yet https://github.com/kvalo/ath11k-firmware

Comment: @darth_epoxy Is sad. I need wait, when support 'Qualcomm Atheros QCNFA765' will add in Ubuntu?

Comment: I don't see any news in launchpad so sorry no news. Try replacing bluetooth with ath11k_pci ion you dmesg query and it might tell us where it's failing. Most likely however you need to wait a week then update you firmware or google for kernel updates relating to your hardware. Perhaps @guiverc will find this question and help us.

Comment: I will also search around stack overflow if someone got the same question; or similar;

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are talking about "wait a week and then update the firmware" because I am a new Ubuntu user.
But thanks too much for tried to help me!

Comment: Please add output of `lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue`.

Comment: @Pilot6 added..

Comment: `sudo dmesg | grep -i blue`

Comment: @Pilot6  added..

Comment: The device is not supported yet. A patch is needed to add support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This device `0489:e0e1` is not supported by Linux kernel yet.

A patch to `drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c` is needed to add this specific device.

You can create a bug report to Launchpad.

Run `ubuntu-bug linux` and follow directions.

Comment: Can you tell me how i can create a bug report to Launchpad?

Comment: I've added this to the answer. But don't expect it is fast.

Comment: Thanks too much