# Ubuntu bluetooth connectivity problems?

Tags: sound, kernel, bluetooth, headphones, 23.10

I have tried this with Ubuntu 22.10 and 23.10.
The output of `uname -a` is

> Linux linuxwkstation 6.6.16-060616-generic #202402051536 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC
> Mon Feb  5 21:11:50 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I am running on a MacMini 2014.
I went through many StackExchange posts and other sources to get bluetooth to work correctly. Hit and miss, as well as unreliable. Too many hours spent without result. The headphone sometimes worked or iPhone could not connect, etc.

I migrated to the latest kernel 6.6.16 - the latest Ubuntu is behind 6.5.0-10.10.  The big difference is the improvements made in respect to bluetooth in 6.6.0 onwards.

Now, if I switch on my Bose headset it connects immediately, and I can conference or listen to music, as well as switch devices via the bluetooth utility.

Comment: Please split this into a question and a self-answer part.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site, not a discussion forum. In this site you ask a question and get answers from other users. You are most welcome to answer your own question by clicking the **Answer Your Own Question** button below. You should check out the site [Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help) and read the sections about how to ask questions and how to write good answer for this site. It is good practice to mention the version of Ubuntu you are running in your question.

Comment: You may want to add some info about the Bluetooth chip in your computer in your question. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1450767/bluetooth-does-not-work-on-ubuntu-22-04) for the kind of information you should provide in your question. Without the hardware information, the question is not answerable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bluetooth does not work on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1450767/bluetooth-does-not-work-on-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: The link : Bluetooth does not work on Ubuntu 22.04 – user68186 does not work, for the very reason given in the "Answer to the question".  The kernel used in the example is deficient in support of bluetooth (and as described as a focus area in kernel 6.6).  By upgrading the kernel, as described, the issues are usually resolved.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/07/27/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-end-of-life-reached-on-july-20-2023/   *The kernels you mention aren't Ubuntu supported kernels either so your details are vague; 6.5 is the 23.10 kernel with other OEM options; 6.6 is the current noble kernel & 6.8 the testing noble kernel, with Ubuntu noble off-topic until released*

Answer (score 1):

I migrated to the latest kernel 6.6.16 - the latest Ubuntu is behind 6.5.0-10.10. The big difference is the improvements made in respect to bluetooth in 6.6.0 onwards.

Now, if I switch on my Bose headset it connects immediately, and I can conference or listen to music, as well as switch devices via the bluetooth utility.

1. Step One:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   OPTIONAL: reboot (best practice?)
   ```
2. Step two:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt-get install mainline
   ```
3. Step three:

   - Press "Show Apps" AND
   - select Mainline Kernels AND
   - wait for loading of all kernels AND
   - select 6.6.16 *(No higher than this!!! Latest at this point in time. Later versions are NOT supported/production ready)* AND
   - select Install and wait for the process to be completed AND
   - select Exit THEN
   - reboot

And now your bluetooth problems should be resolved!