# Ubuntu 22.04. I have the 'Bluetooth not found, use dongle' error. Asking me to merge the ar3k folder. Safe to do?

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth

I followed the instructions here: [Patch file not found ar3k/AthrBT_0x31010000.dfu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403934/patch-file-not-found-ar3k-athrbt-0x31010000-dfu) When I copy the ar3k folder to lib/firmware it's asking me if I want to merge. Yikes! I'm a Linux newbie so I have no idea. Could the merge and reboot create all kinds of problems? Is it safe to do? I really, really don't want to hose my system.

[image: Will this merge trash my system?]

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed. It fixed itself. After I finished writing and posting this question, the Bluetooth is now working (and I didn't do a reboot). I have no idea why it started working again. shrug

Just in case the problem happens again, is it safe to do the folder merge?